# arduino connected to zigbee shield rebooting itself

Tags: arduino

I am using an arduino board and I have connected a Zigbee shield to the board. A switch is connected to one of the gpios available with the arduino board.

The problem is when I press the switch at a very high frequency the arduino board is resetting itself. When any other zigbee is powered on then the board is not rebooting. Please suggest some solution for this problem.

Comment: Does the problem happen when the shield is not connected ? Are you using what power source ? USB ?

Comment: This problem is not repeated when the shield is not connected. I am using external 12Volts power adapter.

Comment: I am facing exactly same issue.I have tried flushing the serial stream and doing a dummy read before writing to serial(Xbee)..but nothing worked..let me know if you found a solution

Comment: I have tried doing the same things but nothing worked for me too

Comment: Have you tried adding a capacitor between your 5V and GND lines?